# How to extract the version info using regex in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy, pattern-matching

I have a string as `<tr><td>Version:</td><td>6.3.13.2</td></tr>` I want to extract `6.3.13.2` from this. How can I do so in Groovy regex, please help.

Comment: `<td>([\d.]+)</td>` should work. I.e. `def ver = (versionXml =~ /<td>([\d.]+)<\/td>/)[0][1]`

Comment: `String version = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text).td[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example presented, you can use:

```
/[\d.]+/
```

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/SKN6gu/1)

Answer (score 1):

For the example provided you could use a simple regular expressions like this

```
/[\d.]+/
```

It would be better if you use

```
(?:<td>)([\d.]+)(?:<\/td>)
```

and take this capture group and replace it what you want.
Learn about regular expressions here
[REGEX Library, tester, documentation, cheat sheet](http://allregex.com)